# Error in writing Python functions in Crystal-lang

Tags: python, python-c-api, crystal-lang

I am trying to write some python function in crystal-lang through the C Python API.

My code follows:

```
METH_VARARGS  = 0x0001

@[Link("python3.5m")]
lib Python
  alias PyObject = Void*

  struct PyMethodDef
    name  : UInt8*
    func  : Void*
    flags : LibC::Int
    doc   : UInt8*
  end

  fun Py_Initialize
  fun Py_Finalize
  fun PyObject_CallObject(func : PyObject, args : PyObject) : PyObject
  fun PyCFunction_NewEx(method : PyMethodDef*, __self__ : PyObject, ) : PyObject
  fun PyLong_AsLong(n : PyObject) : Int64
  fun PyLong_FromLong(n : Int64) : PyObject

end

def new_method_def(name : String, function, flags : LibC::Int)
  x = Pointer(Python::PyMethodDef).malloc(1)
  x.value.name  = name.to_unsafe
  x.value.func  = function
  x.value.flags = flags
  x.value.doc   = nil
  x
end

Python.Py_Initialize

a = ->(args : Void*) { 
                       puts Python.PyLong_AsLong(args)
                       Pointer(Void).null 
                     }

name     = "num"
number   = Python.PyLong_FromLong(1) 
Python.Py_IncRef(number)
method   = Python.PyCFunction_NewEx(new_method_def(name,a.pointer,METH_VARARGS),number)
Python.PyObject_CallObject(method,Pointer(Void).null)

Python.Py_Finalize
```

Everything works if I set `nil` instead of `number` when in `PyCFunction_NewEx`, but as the code is, it throws an invalid acces memory exception when `Py_Finalize` is called. 
I can't understand what's causing it. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't know the Crystal bindings around the C-API, but `PyCFunction_NewEx` takes the two parameters from `PyCFunction_New` (the method object and a `self`) plus a `PyObject *module`. So, I don't know why this even compiles, since you're passing two arguments to a C function of three parameters. If it compiles, I suppose there's a good chance the third argument will end up being all 0's so it'll be read as a null module, which would work by accident. But passing the int value `1` as the `self` argument doesn't seem right.

Comment: Or maybe Crystal is somehow adding a `self` for you somewhere… in which case you're passing the int `1` as the module. Obviously it isn't a module object, and if the interpreter just assumes it is without checking, I could easily see that segfaulting.

Comment: Can you explain (a) what this function is supposed to do, and (b) which parameter of `PyCFunction_New` you were trying to pass `number` as and why you thought that would make sense, it might be easier to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @abarnert This code is just a test to see if this kind of stuff works. I am creating an embedded language and I'd like to pass some function from this language to python. The only way is to pass a crystal proc to python through a PyCFuncObject. I also have to pass some data to this proc to execute the method of my language, and this is why I was trying to set an int as self. But the above code works (so you should have 1 printed), the problem raises when Python attempts to free the memory of PyCFuncObject.

Comment: Here is what I don't understand: where is the invalid pointer which makes the program crash? And I'm pretty sure it is when I set self...

Comment: Why are you calling `PyCFunction_NewEx` instead of `PyCFunction_New`? And, given that you _are_ calling it, why are you only passing it 2 arguments instead of 3? I don't know what Crystal does there (it really ought to be catchable as an error, the way it would be even in C89…), but if it's not doing anything magical, you're just passing whatever pointer happens to be sitting in some register or stack position as a pointer to a module object. Whether that segfaults or not is basically the luck of the draw, and it's not all that surprising that minor, seemingly-unrelated changes affect that.

Comment: If you really want to see what's different, you could try running in a debugger to see what ends up as the third parameter's value inside `PyCFunction_NewEx` in the two cases. (My guess is that's it's just 0 when it works, while the value it gets when it doesn't is an obviously invalid pointer, e.g., maybe 1.) But I don't see what there is of interest to learn there. If you're writing invalid code that shouldn't work but because of undefined behavior occasionally it does, who cares why it occasionally does?

Comment: @abarnert I am calling PyCFunction_NewEx because PyCFunction_New is a marco in the source code. And I am passing only two parameters because that's the definition I always got from the source code. But I can try to add a third parameter. What crystal does I guess is something like a dlopen with the python library...

Comment: What source are you looking at? First, `PyCFunction_New` should have a function (so it can be linked into the public API) even though it's usually used as a macro, unless you're using 2.6 or 3.2 or something. Meanwhile, `PyCFunction_NewEx` has always taken three parameters.

Comment: @abarnert I'm looking at the Python 3.5 source code, since I'm dealing with it

Comment: [Here is the 3.5 source.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Objects/methodobject.c#L25) Its `NewEx` takes three arguments. And it has `New` as a function, not just as a macro. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I don't know why I do have a different source code... I got it from GitHub... I'm gonna try to fix this first, then I let you know

Comment: What does `git branch` say? Is it some work-in-progress (that never finished) branch forked off of 3.5 or something rather than 3.5 itself? (Although I honestly can't imagine why any WIP would change `NewEx` to remove the third parameter, it's not completely impossible.)

Comment: @abarnert I just downloaded the 3.5 branch as a .zip file, but I don't seriously know why I do have a different code. I'm going to update it.

Comment: If you're anything like me, you can't train yourself not to fat-finger your way into accidentally editing code while just looking at it, but you can train yourself to work around the problem. if I thought I was just deleting my current isearch query, but I'd actually finished the search and deleted the found expression… my editor shows me that my I have local diffs. Or, if I can't use emacs, I can `git status` from the shell before spending hours debugging my stupidity. One more reason to use a git clone instead of a downloaded zip whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem here is that you're calling a C function of three parameters with only two arguments.

Regrettably, [`PyCFunction_NewEx` is missing from the documentation, despite being a public API function.](https://bugs.python.org/issue16776) But all of the examples using it pass three arguments. And if you go to [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/methodobject.c#L27):

```
PyObject *
PyCFunction_NewEx(PyMethodDef *ml, PyObject *self, PyObject *module)
```

That's 3.7, but this is the same [in 3.5](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Objects/methodobject.c#L25) and [in 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/methodobject.c#L16), and in every other version since the function was added to the API [in 2.3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.3/Objects/methodobject.c#L9). The whole point of `NewEx` is to allow you to pass a module.

Presumably, the function is expecting that third argument either in a register or on the stack, and you haven't put anything there, so it's completely arbitrary what you're passing. Slightly different code will leave completely different values in those places, so it's not surprising that you get different results:

- If the value happens to be 0, that's fine; you're allowed to pass `NULL` as the `module` value.
- If the value happens to be something that points to unmapped memory, like, say, `1` (as in the raw C long/long long, not a PyLongObject), you should get a segfault from the attempt to `incref` the module.
- If the value happens to be a pointer to some random thing in memory, the incref will work, but will corrupt that random thing. Which could do just about anything, but a mysterious segfault at some arbitrary later point is almost the *least* surprising thing it could do.

---

Meanwhile, from a comment:

> I am calling PyCFunction_NewEx because PyCFunction_New is a marco in the source code.

If you're using Python 2.3-2.6 or 3.0-3.2, then sure. But in later versions, including the 3.5 you say you're using, CPython goes out of its way to define `PyCFunction_New` as a function specifically so that it will be present in the API (and even the stable API, for 3.x). See [3.5](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Objects/methodobject.c#L16) for example:

```
/* undefine macro trampoline to PyCFunction_NewEx */
#undef PyCFunction_New

PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *)
PyCFunction_New(PyMethodDef *ml, PyObject *self)
{
    return PyCFunction_NewEx(ml, self, NULL);
}
```

So, you really can just call `PyCFunction_New`.

Comment: The Crystal compiler can't raise any error because it doesn't know the API of the python library. That's what the `lib` definition is for, it's essentially the same as a C header.
If the header definition is incorrect in C, you call a function with a missing argument, and a C compiler can't complain about this either.

Comment: @JohannesMüller So it doesn't parse the C headers at any point to check? OK, got it.

Comment: Nope. It's all in Crystal.

Comment: @abarnert Adding a third parameter to PyCFunction_NewEx the code stopped crashing. This means the problem was caused by that stuff: the `module` parameter was a garbage pointer which lead to a segfault error